# Trying to convert each tuple inside a list to a list in using forloop in python

Tags: python, list, casting, tuples

I'm trying to convert each tuple inside users to a list. I tried the following code to achieve that:

```
usernames = ["Dude","Bro","Mister",]
passwords = ("bloke","black","nobbe",)
users = list(zip(usernames,passwords))


for i in users:
    i = list(i)

print(users)
```

My expected output for print(users) was:
`[['Dude', 'bloke'], ['Bro', 'black'], ['Mister', 'nobbe']]`

But print(user) gave me the following, leaving the tuples unchanged:
`[('Dude', 'bloke'), ('Bro', 'black'), ('Mister', 'nobbe')]`

How can convert each tuple inside users to a list?

Comment: So, nowhere do you modify your list in your code. This is an important point to understand - why did you *expect* the list to change here at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as simple as

```py
users = [list(u) for u in users]
```

or like this, if you don't want a list comprehension.

```py
for index, u in enumerate(users):
    users[index] = list(u)
```

Please read [this article](https://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/lists.html#lists-are-mutable) to have a better understanding about lists in Python.

Comment: How would I do it without list comprehension?

Comment: It's very important to understand, two different things are happening here.

Answer (score 0):

use for loop as below:

```
for i in range(len(users)):
    users[i] = list(users[i])
```